# TypeScript + Mocha + Express - TypeError: app.address is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, mocha.js

In converting an API from ES6 to TypeScript, I'm running into this issue when trying to run unit tests against the Express REST Endpoints:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined
```

I've re-arranged the code a bit for loading the server, but it's basically like this:

***server.ts***

```
import App from './app';

...bunch of imports...

new App([..., new Controller()]);
```

***app.ts***

```
export default class App {
    constructor(controllers) {
        this.app = express();

        this.initControllers(controllers);
    }

    initControllers(controllers) {
        controllers.forEach((controller) => {
            controller.setupRoutes(this.app);
        }
    }

}
```

And then each Controller consists of at a minimum the `setupRoutes()` function, that would look something like this:

```
setupRoutes(app: Application): void {
    app.get(`/myRoute`, this.heartbeat);
}
```

When trying to call the route in the Spec file (which are still JS), I've imported both the `../../build/app.js` and the `../../build/server.js` files. Passing into supertest as the following produced these results:

```
const server = require('../../build/server.js');
const app = require('../../build/app.js');
```

`let supertest = require('supertest')(app);`
**Yields:** `TypeError: app.address is not a function`

`let supertest = require('supertest')(app.default);`
**Yields:** `Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor App cannot be invoked without 'new'`

The tests themselves are just ES6, and not TS. I'm not looking to convert the tests over to TS yet, and would like to still use ES6 for them, at this time.

Comment: Are you missing the export? I do not see an export in server.ts

Comment: @sparrow server.ts is really just a convenience loader that instantiates the app with an array of the controllers to load, as I have to import then load manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass an http.Server, or a Express app to `supertest`, your `app` (`const app = require('../../build/app.js');`) just is a wrap class.

What you need to pass to `supertest` is `appInstance.app`

My suggestion:

Make express instance in you App to public:

```
export default class App {
  constructor(controllers) {
    this.app = express();

    this.initControllers(controllers);
  }

  initControllers(controllers) {
    controllers.forEach((controller) => {
      controller.setupRoutes(this.app);
    });
  }

  // express instance getter
  getExpressInstance(): Application {
    return this.app;
  }

}
```

Then, in your `server.ts`, you have to export the App instance:

```
import App from './app';

...bunch of imports...

const app = new App([..., new Controller()]);

export default app;
```

Finally, in your `supertest` file:

```
const AppInstance = require('../../build/server.js');
// const app = require('../../build/app.js'); <----- remove unused import

let supertest = require('supertest')(AppInstance.getExpressInstance());
```

Comment: Many thanks! I was all turned around trying to see what to do. My REST API Tests are now working again :)